# list of system drives

Tags: powershell-3.0, disk-partitioning

I have a system with multiple boot partitions(C and D). On this system, I have some other volumes that are for data. Is there anyway I can retrieve all system partitions using power shell? I have googled for solution but couldn't find much help. Any ideas or starting point could be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enumerate volumes using `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume`. However, the `BootVolume` property will only indicate the *current* boot volume. System folders of other Windows installations are not recognized.

You could check for the presence of a Windows folder or kernel file on other partitions:

```psh
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | ? {
  $_.DriveLetter -and
  (Test-Path -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.Name 'Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe'))
} | select -Expand DriveLetter
```

Beware, though, that this check requires the other volume(s) to actually have a drive letter assigned to them, and is easily fooled if someone creates a spurious file `\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe` on a drive.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Get-PSDrive', e.g.:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849796.aspx

Comment: so if I have C, D and E drive with C and D are the system boot partitions, this will return all C, D and E. Correct? How can I know which of these are system drives?

Comment: Yep it will return all partitions.  If you need to filter further, you can use Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume which allows you to filter through more options.  I don't have a computer with multiple partitions and things to test on at the moment but you can find more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx